# key parameter issue in ReactJS Hooks, updating all Products items when using (add/subtract) indivisually

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am kind of confused when applying the key parameter to the below code in ReactJS, i understand we need to use the key parameter to uniquely identify each DOM element, when i tried to use key={index} in buttons it comes up with error(Encountered two children with the same key).

I am also a bit puzzled here, as updating the `setQuantity` update all the items in all products(as shown in screenshot below), not sure how i can use the unique key item to update each product quantity only.

Any help appreciated.

**Update 1:** the code is now updated with key={productName}, but still the adding/ subtracting value is updating across all products when adding/subtracting single product

```js
function Home({ props }) {
  //quantitiyselected, to set the no. of items purchased
  const [quantitiyselected, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  // below function to add, subtract quantity
  let selectquantity = (e) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.name == "add") {
      let i = quantitiyselected + 1;
      setQuantity(i);
    } else if (e.currentTarget.name == "subtract" && quantitiyselected > 0) {
      let z = quantitiyselected - 1;
      setQuantity(z);
    } else;
  };

  return (
    <div className="products">
      {props.map((eachproduct, index) => {
        let productName = eachproduct.product_name;
        let producNumber = eachproduct.producNumber;
        let price = eachproduct.price;
        let desc = eachproduct.productDescription;
        let photo = eachproduct.image_URL;
        let stockQuantity = eachproduct.stockQuantity;
        return (
          <div className="products" key={productName }>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <img className="products-image" src={photo} />
              </li>
              <li>{productName} </li>
              <li>
                Item No:{producNumber}(InStock:{stockQuantity})
              </li>
              <li>price:{price}£ </li>
              <li>{desc}</li>
              <li>
                <ButtonGroup aria-label="quantityofproduct">
                  <Button
                    
                    variant="secondary"
                    name="subtract"
                    value="subtract"
                    onClick={selectquantity}
                  >
                    -
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="secondary">
                    {quantitiyselected}
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    
                    variant="secondary"
                    name="add"
                    value="add"
                    onClick={selectquantity}
                  >
                    +
                  </Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
                &nbsp;
                 variant="primary">
                  Buy
                </Button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `key={index}` to multiple elements in your render (`<div>`, `<ul>` and each `<Button />`), but it only needs to go on the top level element that is being rendered in the array which in your case is the `<div className="products">`.

As an aside, an array index is generally *not* a good candidate for the key - it should be unique to each item that is being rendered. In your example, I think `producNumber` would be the best bet as I am assuming it is some unique identifier to each product.

- remove `key={index}` from everything that you have it on
- add `key={producNumber}` to the inner `<div className="products">`

[This](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop) is a good resource to learn more about React's `key` prop.

---

The reason every product has the same quantity, is you only have a single number for your state:

```
React.useState(0);
```

You are trying to track quantities per product, so you would need a quantity for each product. One way you could do that is by using an object (`{}`) that has properties of your `producNum` and quantity as their value. For example:

```js
const products = [
  { name: "thing", num: 152 },
  { name: "other-thing", num: 254 },
];

const initialQuantities = products.reduce(
  (quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.num]: 0 }),
  {}
);

console.log(initialQuantities);
```

This creates the object with each product with an initial quantity of 0.

When you then increase or decrease the quantity, you would pass the product number of the product you clicked to the function, and then you can set the new quantity of just that product, while leaving the other product quantities untouched by using [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const initialQuantities = products.reduce(
  (quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.producNumber]: 0 }),
  {}
);

const [quantities, setQuantities] = React.useState(initialQuantities);

const increase = (productNum) => {
  setQuantities({
    ...quantities,
    [productNum]: quantities[productNum] + 1,
  });
};

const decrease = (productNum) => {
  setQuantities({
    ...quantities,
    [productNum]: Math.max(0, quantities[productNum] - 1),
  });
};
```

and then your `onClick` would become:

```
onClick={() => increase(producNumber)}
```

and

```
onClick={() => decrease(producNumber)}
```

A simple implementation can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dust-nbetq?file=/src/App.js:175-655

Comment: thanks, i have updated the code giving top level the key value only. But i am still facing the issue with useState,as updating one product updates all products but i am looking to use that functionality individually to each product. i think i have to integrate the key value to the useState to relate but cant figure out how as i understand we can only update one value using useState.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, it does work perfectly in my code, although it took me a while to go through and understand the code as i am still learning :)        from the code there are two points that i still cant understand how it works maybe if you can please explain.

Comment: 1) if i  understand the reduce function correctly, so here it goes to each object in an array(products) and take the values(152,254) and use them as key in the new object   but how quantities works her as we haven't define/assign quantities variable in the start....  and whats the point of {} in the end                                                                                                                                const initialQuantities = products.reduce(
  (quantities, product) => ({ ...quantities, [product.num]: 0 }),
  {}
);     Thank you

Comment: 2) also from the same reduce code [product.num] confuses me too when reading, as i think .num we take from products array and  join with product  new variable i think

Comment: 1) I would definitely take a look over the `reduce` docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce, but basically what it is doing is going over every product and adding the product number as a new property on the result object, with a value of 0 to represent the initial quantity. The `{}` at the end is the initial value for the `reduce` - since we are creating an object, this is just an empty object to start.

Comment: 2) This is bracket notation so you can use a variable to define the property on an object. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors and scroll down to Bracket Notation. A quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t9bh7mef/

Comment: Thanks again Anthony, i will give it a go.